# Read serial input with awk, insert date

Tags: awk, serial-port

I'm trying to reformat serial input, which consists of two integers separated by a comma (sent from an Arduino):

```
1,2
3,4
0,0
0,1
```

etc. I would like to append the date after each line, separating everything with a tab character. Here's my code so far:

```
cat /dev/cu.usbmodem3d11 | awk 'BEGIN {RS=","};{printf "%i\t%i\t%s",$1,$2,system("date")}'
```

Here's the result I get (with date in my locale):

```
1   2   0Mer 26 fév 2014 22:09:20 EST
3   4   0Mer 26 fév 2014 22:09:20 EST
0   0   0Mer 26 fév 2014 22:09:20 EST
0   1   0Mer 26 fév 2014 22:09:20 EST
```

Why is there an extra '0' in front of my date field? Sorry for the newbie question :(

**EDIT** This code solved my problem. Thanks to all who helped.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","};{system("date")|getline myDate;printf "%i\t%i\t%s",$1, $2, myDate}' /dev/cu.usbmodem3d11
```

I'm not clear why, but in order for the date to keep updating and recording at what time the data was received, I have to use `system("date")`instead of just `"date"`in the code above.

Comment: You should try to avoid using `cat` with programs that can read file itself, like  `awk`.  Eks `awk 'code' /dev/cu.usbmodem3d11`

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use awk?  You could do this easily enough in pure shell (bash or posix) without a call to an additional language interpreter.

Comment: @Jotne good point, will update accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things

It will be easier to see your problem if you add a `\n` at the end of your `printf` string

Then the output is

```
>echo '1,2' | awk 'BEGIN {RS=","};{printf "%i\t%i\t%s\n",$1,$2,system("date")}'
Wed Feb 26 21:30:17 CST 2014
1       0       0
Wed Feb 26 21:30:17 CST 2014
2       0       0
```

I'm guessing that output from `system("date")` returns its output "outside" of scope of awk's `$0` natural scope of each line of input processed. Others may be able to offer a better explanation.

To get the output you want, I'm using the `getline` function to capture the output of the `date` command to a variable (`myDt`). Now the output is

```
> echo '1,2' | awk 'BEGIN {RS=","};{"date" | getline myDt ; printf "%i\t%i\t%s\n",$1,$2,myDt}'
1       0       Wed Feb 26 21:31:15 CST 2014

2       0       Wed Feb 26 21:31:15 CST 2014
```

Finally, we remove the "debugging" `\n` char, and get the output you specify:

```
> echo '1,2' | awk 'BEGIN {RS=","};{"date" | getline myDt ; printf "%i\t%i\t%s",$1,$2,myDt}'
1       0       Wed Feb 26 21:34:56 CST 2014
2       0       Wed Feb 26 21:34:56 CST 2014
```

And, per Jaypal's post, I see now that `FS=","` is another issue, so when we make that change AND return the `\n' char, we have

```
echo '1,2' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","};{"date" | getline myDt ; printf "%i\t%i\t%s\n",$1,$2,myDt}'
1       2       Wed Feb 26 21:44:42 CST 2014
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, the date never increments using this code  either (see other comment by user gothi on other solution). My guess is that the "date" | getline command is executed only once.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need the date to reflect when the data was read (streamed from the serial port).

Comment: By using the code as is, the date never gets updated. By using `system("date") | getline myDt` instead, the date is updated.

Comment: I would expect `"date"| getline myDt` to work for each line of data that is read. I don't have time to test it now. Did you let this run for a while? And you still get same date? If so, then thanks for sharing! And in either case, I'm glad to have helped. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

**Two issues:**

**First** - `RS` is record separator. You need `FS` which is Field Separator to separate two columns, where `$1` will be `1` and `$2` will be `2` (as per your first row)

**Second** - The extra `0` you see in output is the return value of `system()` command. It means it ran successfully. You can simply run the shell command in quotes and pipe it to `getline`. Putting a variable after it will allow you to capture the value returned.

**Try this:**

```
 awk 'BEGIN {FS=","};{"date"|getline var;printf "%i\t%i\t%s\n",$1,$2,var}'
```

Comment: Same here, the date doesn't get incremented.

Comment: By using the code as is, the date never gets updated. By using `system("date") | getline var` instead, the date is updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more simple solution:

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2,dt}' dt="$(date)" OFS="\t" /dev/cu.usbmodem3d11
1       2       Thu Feb 27 06:23:41 CET 2014
3       4       Thu Feb 27 06:23:41 CET 2014
0       0       Thu Feb 27 06:23:41 CET 2014
0       1       Thu Feb 27 06:23:41 CET 2014
```

IF you like to show date in another format, just read manual for `date`
Eks `dt="$(date +%D)"` gives `02/27/14`

Comment: Doesn't this run the `date` command *only once*, when awk first runs?  If this is running on a `tail -f`, the date will never change.