# Bash getting everything to the same line?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have been working on this all morning with no luck. I need the results to be all on one line comma delimited. Some portions were working fine but once I added the read it feel apart!

```
INPUT=steamIPs.csv
   OLDIFS=$IFS
   IFS=,
   [ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
   while read router contact address
   do 
   myvar="$ip 
   $router
   $contact
   $address"
   echo "$myvar" | paste -s -d',' 
   OUTPUT=`snmpget $ip  -c public -v 1 sysuptim`    
   echo ${OUTPUT#*:} | tr -d ' '
   done < $INPUT 
   IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: more info on what the input looks like and what is the expected output would be appreciated

Comment: Agree about more info.  Also, the IFS and OLDIFS variables definitely need to be in quotes: OLDIFS="$IFS" and IFS="$OLDIFS"

Comment: don't make us guess about your required output format. Please update question to include sample inputs (1 line from $INPUT), and what is in $OUTPUT, AND THEN what you expect those 2 inputs to look like as output. Good luck.

Comment: This can probably be an awk 1-liner. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058379/read-serial-input-with-awk-insert-date, and substitute `date` with your `snmpget ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanka for your time and sorry for not givving more info the output should look like this but all on one line: 172.0.0.1, bob,Bob@gmail.com

Comment: @DanBliss, you don't need quotes in an assignment: word splitting is not performed during assignments. Documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working too hard:

```
if [[ ! -f "$INPUT" ]]; then
    echo "$INPUT file not found"
    exit 99
fi

while IFS=, read -r router contact address; do 
    myvar="$ip,$router,$contact,$address"
    echo "$myvar"
done < "$INPUT"
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would have worked but the return is too long.